# Find a basis for the set of vectors of magnitude $1$

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

> Is it possible to find a basis for the set of vectors that have a magnitude of 1?

I've studied a bit of linear algebra in school, and if the question can be answered with linear algebra, I can't think of it. Would appreciate some help.

**Attempt**

Let $S$ be the set of vectors $\begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{bmatrix}$ such that $x_1^2 + x_2^2 = 1$

I thought of writing $x_1$ and $x_2$ in terms of an angle $\theta$, but I don't know where to go from there either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the other answer points out, it doesn't really make sense to ask for a "basis" (in the sense of vector spaces) for something that isn't a vector space. There isn't a particularly deep reason that this is true, it's just due to how vector spaces and bases are defined: in particular, we only define a "basis of $V$" where $V$ is some vector space; that's it.

---

It would be OK to ask if you can *parameterize* your set $S$ -- and indeed, you can. This is essentially how the longitude/latitude system for the Earth works; we specify a point on the Earth's surface by specifying two angles (one measuring North/South from the equator, another measuring East/West from some specified starting "line"). So you can use two parameters to specify a point in $S$ but doing so doesn't yield any sort of "basis" because $S$ isn't a vector space.

Essentially, the take away here is that linear algebra is not exactly meant to study spheres :)

Answer (score 3):

The issue here is that the collection of all unit vectors in a normed linear space is not a subspace, and therefore cannot have a basis!

For example, $\langle1,0\rangle,\langle0,1\rangle\in\Bbb R^2$ but 
$$
\langle1,0\rangle+\langle0,1\rangle=\langle1,1\rangle
$$
is not a unit vector.

Of course, if you wish to find a basis for a normed linear space *consisting* of unit vectors, simply start with any basis $\mathcal B$ and consider $\mathcal U=\{v/\lVert v\rVert:v\in\mathcal B\}$.

Comment: I think non-subspaces can certainly *contain* bases, unless "contain" has a more specific meaning I'm not aware of.

Comment: I understand that $S$ is not a subspace. I didn't know that non-subspaces couldn't contain bases. Could you tell me why that is? Edit: OK, now I'm confused after looking at pjs36's response. Can a non-subspace contain a basis?

Comment: The question asks: "Is it possible to find a basis for the set of vectors that have a magnitude of 1?" 

To me, it is nonsensical to ask if a set of vectors has a basis if the set is not a subspace. To more accurately represent the question I've changed "contain" in my answer to "have".

Comment: OK. Sorry to bother you with this again, but I'm having a bit of trouble understanding, why is it nonsensical for us to ask if a non-subspace has a basis?

Comment: How would a basis for a non-subspace be defined?

Comment: What would you expect as an answer to your question "find a basis of this subset of $V$ that is not a subspace"? A basis for the smallest subspace that contains this set? In case of your set of all unit vectors, this subspace would be the whole vector space $V$.

Comment: @Brian Fitzpatrick - A set of linearly independent vectors such that any vector in the set S can be written as a linear combination of the vectors in the basis.

Comment: Under that definition, a basis for unit vectors is simply a basis for all of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Makes sense. I understand now Thanks.